# Oracle (XE) & SQL-Developer: how to find out the time/date/timestamp format being used?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently wrote a tool that extracts certain data from our DBs. It runs as PL/SQL script running in SQLDeveloper (either in a worksheet or as extension plugin) and produces its output to the SQLDeveloper log-window.

This worked all fine on my system, but now I encountered an issue when users are on systems with a different language or more specific with different default time/date/timestamp formats than on the machine on which I had been developing and testing this.

Now - I am not sure: is the format of dates, times and timestamps controlled by the DB or by SLQ-Developer? In my understanding these PL/SQL scripts are sent to the DB for execution and their output is sent back to SQL-Developer. That would mean for me, that the format of the output depends solely on the DB (or the system on which the DB executes). Or are the NLS setting of the client (SQL-Developer) somehow involved here?

To make my tool auto-adjust to these settings I will need to be able to query these formats - either from the DB in use (Oracle 12.2 or Oracle XE 18/19 in our case) or from SQLDeveloper.

Assuming, it's the DB: Is there a table that contains the default format strings that are being used for select results?

Note: The point is NOT how to format dates etc. as strings, but the other way round: 
I get the the query results as strings in the log-window. These contain dates and timestamps. I now need a hint from the DB-system to figure out how to interpret these. E.g. when I get a date such as '10-11-12', is this meant to be Nov. 10th, 2012 or is meant to be Nov. 12th, 2010?

Hope I could make myself clear...

Comment: it's controlled by your session, you have a NLS_DATE_FORMAT set by sqldeveloper at startup - see your Database Preferences

Comment: Do it the other way round: use DATE (and TIMESTAMP) constants that are **independent** of the NLS settings, e.g. ANSI literals: `date '2020-02-14'` or `timestamp '2020-02-14 16:41:42'` and never convert them to a string without providing a format mask, e.g. `to_char(some_date_column, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` instead of `to_char(some_date_column)`

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Can I access or query that format from within a PL/SQL script?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The problem I have here is, that I query those fields generically (i.e. I get ALL values already as strings at first). Thus I need said hint to be able to interpret these strings correctly when converting them to a date or time(stamp) for later use.

Comment: Yes, query the nls_session data dictionary views